# Perf report's function at 0xffffffffffffffff

Tags: performance, linux-kernel, perf

I am trying to grok what myApp is very busy with (90% cpu single thread). It is a server that i shouldn't restart. I've collected samples by

```
perf record -p 5068 -F 99 --call-graph dwarf sleep 10
```

And `perf report` gives me this:

```
+  100.00%     0.00%  myApp    [unknown]              [.] 0xffffffffffffffff                                                                                                                           ◆
+   80.67%     0.67%  myApp    myApp                  [.] pipeline_run                                                                                                                                 ▒
+   67.71%     0.00%  myApp    myApp                  [.] QueryProcessor::process
```

I spent some time googling and reading docs, and I suspect that 0xffffffffffffffff could not be resolved because `perf` does not know where stack bottom is as it didn't start that process. But could someone confirm it or point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my case this was caused by `perf` using a too small stack dump size. That will cause the bottom of the truncated stack to become `0xffffffffffffffff`, which will make `perf report` and friends think that the function `0xffffffffffffffff` is used a lot.

When I used the maximum stack dump capture size, I got rid of most of the `0xffffffffffffffff`. If you pass `--call-graph dwarf` the default stack dump size of `8192` will be used. To maximize it, change to `--call-graph dwarf,65528`.

From `perf record --help`:

```
    When "dwarf" recording is used, perf also records (user) stack dump
    when sampled.  Default size of the stack dump is 8192 (bytes).
    User can change the size by passing the size after comma like
    "--call-graph dwarf,4096".
```

If you try with a value larger than `65528` you get

```
callchain: Incorrect stack dump size (max 65528): 128000
```

Comment: perfect! That really helps. Upvoted.